# how to insert a data to a google spread sheet with out authorization

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to learn how to use google data API's and i am trying to insert a row to a google spreadsheet which has been made public. The URL of the spreadsheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1thx0Mzts4rZ6Q7gLP_5zeXTmrOBMzsQtanJhBXg3er0/pubhtml

and the source code i am using for this is -

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GoogleDocs {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("GoogleDocsUsingGdataApi");

        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/public/basic");   

        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
        System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

        // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.

        WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
        List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
        WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

        // Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
        URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
        ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

        // Create a local representation of the new row.
        ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("firstname", "Joe");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("lastname", "Smith");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("email", "joesmith@gmail.com");    

        // Send the new row to the API for insertion.
        row = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);

    }
}
```

This code is not inserting any data into the spreadsheet. Can you please tell me whats wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you  have permissions to edit the sheet?

Comment: The spreadsheet is public, but anonymous edits are not allowed. Create a service account and log in with that.

Comment: Alex, you should reply as an answer, so we can upvote you.

Comment: @TheLostMind yes i have permission to edit the sheet.

Comment: @AlexR i didn't get you.

Comment: Am i not supposed to insert the spreadsheet's URL in my code? And the code i am using is from this website- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/  , here they have not mentioned about where we are supposed to use the URL of my spreadsheet. Maybe its because they are using OAuth, but i don't want to use any authorization as such.

Answer (score 0):

Open the spreadsheet URL in a browser where you are not logged into Google and you'll see that you can't edit the sheet anonymously. At least I couldn't.

[Create a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and use that to log in, then you should be able to edit your sheet.

See the link above how to create a `GoogleCredential`, then use the credential to open the service:

```
myService = new SpreadsheetService(appname);
myService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```